# Trying to hide a big scratch on iPhone 6S screen

Tags: screen, iphone, scratches

I've always been a "naked iPhone" kinda guy since I love the design and hate the way cases feel in my pocket. I've managed pretty well for the past 6 or 7 years, and even when I DO get scratches I don't really mind. My latest iPhone, though, somehow got a pretty large scratch across the front (and a smaller one above that).

The thing is, I'm worried that I won't be able to trade it back in to T-mobile with a big ugly scratch on the screen. I know there's no way to "fix" a scratch, but I'm wondering if there are ways to lessen it--or at least make it look better. I've googled this several times and come up with things like toothpaste or vaseline, but I've also read that some of these things can make the screen worse.

I've also read that screen protectors can make scratches look better (and I've already ordered one), but when I return it to T-mobile I'll probably have to take that off.

Note: I've included a picture of the scratch(es) below, and the slight blurriness of my iPad camera does make the scratch look even worse. Just keep in mind that it's a big scratch, but not quite as deep and nasty as the picture suggests.[image: Scratch]

Answer (score 1):

Based on your included picture, I feel that it would be best to research whether T-Mobile accepts this type of return. On the other hand, I think that it would be better off if you just show it as it is, because if they find out that you have hidden a scratch, they might deduct cash. I think you should just trade it in as it is. Even so, http://www.t-mobile.com/cell-phone-trade-in.html states that your device's trade amount will be determined inside the store. So, just leave it as it is.

Comment: Just wondering, why don't you use a tempered glass screen protector? It doesn't ruin the look and feel of the phone and you wouldn't have problems like these ;)

Comment: @RachelS Exactly what she said.

Answer (score 0):

The safest option is to try a screen protector and see if the adhesive covers the jagged scrapes like a bit of liquid would to avoid the diffraction and reflection from the scratch.

Light rubbing by a finger with normal oils and then a light cleaning might be worth exploring.

I personally [would not try to buff it out at all](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/71802/5472) unless imwas prepared with the time needed and for the cost of a paid glass swap repair. Did you get any accident coverage via purchasing method or AppleCare Plus?

Some swaps are as low as $129 at Apple in the US. Other models are more costly.

- https://support.apple.com/iphone/repair/service/screen-replacement